# If i add a new item in json file, this item don't render on browser page

Tags: css, json, next.js13

To begin with, I added 3 elements, as soon as I achieved the display of these three elements I needed, I added a few more but they did not appear on the browser page, and there was no error.

```
import Image from "next/image"
import getUnits from "../libs/getUnits"

export default async function UnitsPage() {
  const units = await getUnits()
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
        <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">Units</h1>
        
        {units.map(unit => {            
            return (
                <>                                              
                    <div key={unit.id} className="parent">
                        <div className="word-container">
                            <h2 className="word">                                                             
                                {unit.name}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="image-container">
                            <Image
                            src={unit.logo_way}
                            width={50}
                            height={50}
                            className="logo-inside-container"
                            /> 
                        </div>
                        <div className="logo-container">
                            <Image
                            src={unit.img_way}
                            height={200}
                            width={400}                                                  
                            />
                        </div>                                
                    </div>                  
                </>   
            )
            })
        }       
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my main page code⬆️

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Africa Korps",
            "logo_way": "/images/afr_logo.png",
            "img_way": "/images/africakorps.jpg"
        },
    
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Wermacht",
            "logo_way": "/images/wer_logo.png",
            "img_way": "/images/wermacht.jpg"
        },
    
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "British Army",
            "logo_way": "/images/brit_logo.png",
            "img_way": "/images/british army.jpg"
        }     

        
    ]
}
```

This is JSON⬆️

if I add 4 element to the JSON file it will not appear on the page. I don't know why>:(

Answer (score 0):

LOL. I solved the problem. I used a local server through the framework JSON Server, so all I had to do was disable the cache in the browser in developer mode, and everything worked